# Flutter, automatically open a link without submitting textfield

Tags: flutter

I have a problem. I have been approaching flutter for a few days and I don't understand how to solve my doubt. Currently (see below) the code I wrote correctly opens an external url but it does so only when I submit the text field. How can I open that link without submitting the text field? I would like to do this without using *flutter_inappwebview* because it doesn't allow some features that i have created. Thanks a lot

```
class _EmptyTabState extends State<EmptyTab> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    openNewTab("http://onepiecepower.info");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: TextField(
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    openNewTab("http://onepiecepower.info");
                  },
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openNewTab(value) {
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);
    browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      webViewModel: WebViewModel(
          url: Uri.parse(value)
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your `openNewTab` function above `initState()`

```
  void openNewTab(value) {
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);
    browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      webViewModel: WebViewModel(
          url: Uri.parse(value)
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    openNewTab("http://onepiecepower.info");
    super.initState();
  }
```